# How to deserialize and loop through JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to deserialize my JSON with Newtonsoft's Json.NET so I can loop through it with an `foreach` loop.

I know that I have to model my class as my JSON object and I think this is where I come up short.

Also I am not quite sure how to implement the namespace so I basically just put it underneath the @page which doesn't throw and error so I guess that's fine (if this is wrong please let me know).

My files are:

**TodoItem.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public List<Array> tasks { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Tasks.json:**

```
[
    {
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Køb tøj"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "vask tøj"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Gør Rent"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@using WebApplication1
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";

    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("pathtojson");

    List<TodoItem> data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoItem>>(json);

}

@{ 
    foreach(var item in data)
    {
        <p>@item</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay So I figured it out myself, but thank you for looking through my code.

My solution is that i split my code up. So I had a taskcollection and a todoitem so it reflected my json format completly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an collection of `Tasks`.  Each `Task` has `Id` and `Name` properties. 
 This can be modelled by splitting your class and updating to the below:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize as:

```
TodoItem data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TodoItem>(json);

foreach (var task in data.Tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {task.Id}, Name: {task.Name}"); 
}
```

Rather than process the json in the view, I would deserialize the json in the controller then pass the deserialized json (model) back to the view.

```
// controller
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("pathtojson");
    TodoItem data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TodoItem>(json);

    return View(data);    // pass the data the your view
}

// razor view
@model WebApplication1.Models.TodoItem    // define model for view
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
@foreach (var task in Model.Tasks)
{
    <div>Id: @task.Id, Name: @task.Name</div>
}
```

I created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P5MDAs).